# What's unique about a set of n numbers whose order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have 3 sets each with 3 numbers: {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, and {2, 1, 3}.

I'm looking for a property of these numbers that will be the same for sets 1 and 3 because they contain the same numbers but in a different order, but different for sets 1 and 2 and for sets 2 and 3.

Sum, for example, doesn't work because the sum of numbers in {1, 4, 5} is the same as that of numbers in {1, 3, 6}.

Product also doesn't work because the product of numbers in {1, 2, 6} is the same as that of numbers in {1, 3, 4}.

Does anyone have an idea how I can go about doing this if it's even at all possible?

Comment: In general order of elements of a set doesn't matter unless you explicitly say so.  If we ignore the possibility of multisets then you can describe this property as $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Comment: How about equality, since two sets $A,B$ are equal if and only if (1) every element in $A$ is an element of $B$ and (2) every element in $B$ is an element of $A$.

Comment: I think some context would be helpful here. Mathematically, there is nothing to be done; the first and third sets are equal, mathematically, while the second is not equal to the others.

Comment: The sets $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{2,1,3\}$ are both the same set. $\qquad$

Comment: I understand that the order of elements in a set generally doesn't matter and that the first and third set are the same... But I'm interested in a property or value (used to describe a set) that will be the same for sets 1 and 3 but different for 1 and 2.

Comment: That's why context would be helpful. I would use the property "$S$ is equal to $\{1,2,3\}$", which may be true or false for a general set $S$ -- it's true for sets 1 and 3, but not true for the 2nd. But it seems this is something you are not happy with.

Comment: It appears that you want some kind of invariant, and there will almost certainly be a suitable invariant, but you need to specify precisely what the domain of the invariant is if you want someone to give an explicit one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done. Let us say we are comparing two sets, $S_1$ and $S_2$. They don't have to have the same number of elements.

**Note**: this will only work for sets with integer elements.

Let
$$v(S) = \sum_{s \in S} 2^s$$

$v(S)$ is essentially a number in base $2$, that entirely represents the set $S$. The digit at the power $i$ in $v(S)$ is $1$ if $i \in S$ and $0$ otherwise. That is, we can deconstruct $v(S)$ *uniquely* in the following way,

$$v(S) = a_12^1 + a_22^2 + \dots + a_n2^n,$$

where $a_i \in \{0, 1\}$. Then, for the term $a_i2^i$ (for $i \le n$) in the decomposition of $v(S)$, if $a_i = 1$, then $i \in S$. If $a_i = 0$, then $i \notin S$.

Comment: It would be sufficient for $z$ to be $1 + \max(a_i)$, which since these are sets rather than multisets means that $z = 2$ works. But whether or not this helps OP depends on information which isn't disclosed in the question.

Comment: Very well noted. Will simplify the answer.